# ajax not posting, always a blank post

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm going nuts with this. I am requesting ajax call in several places, and none of these ajax calls are working correctly lately. Today I decided to start fresh on a new section with ajax call. It's the same thing with all the other ones. It's been days that ajax data is not posting to controller - always blank.

Here is one of them. I am trying to allow users to vote up/down on click on `CButtonColumn` `{up}{down}`. This view grid "_vote.php" is generated through `renderPartial` using `TbTabs`. On `renderpartial` I did set to `true` on the last param.

Okay, next the grid. Here it is:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'condensed',
    'id'=>'vote',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'columns'=>array(
            array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template' => '{up} {down}',
                    'buttons' => array(
                            'up' => array(
                                    'label'=>'<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>',
                                    'imageUrl'=>false,
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("prod/votecommentup", array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
                                    'click'=>' function(){
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("vote", {
                                        type:"POST",
                                        url:$(this).attr("href"),
                                        success:function(data) {
                                              $.fn.yiiGridView.update(vote);
                                        }
                                    }',
                            ),
                            'down'=> array(
                                    'label'=>'<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
                                    'imageUrl'=>false,
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("prod/votecommentdown", array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
                                    'click'=>' function(){
                                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("vote", {
                                        type:"POST",
                                        url:$(this).attr("href"),
                                        success:function(data) {
                                              $.fn.yiiGridView.update(vote);
                                        }
                                    }',
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Okay... next, the url "prod/votecommentup", which is the nearly identical as votecommentdown. Here it is:

```
public function actionVoteCommentUp($id){
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['VoteThis']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['VoteThis'];
        $model->prototype_review_id = $id;
        $model->user_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
        $model->vote = "Y";
        echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'saved'));
    }echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'not post')); //always give me a no post

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend testing your calls through something like Postman App for chrome. This will give you the ability to debug your API/AJAX calls independent of your view. Once you have ensured the API/AJAX is functioning correctly, you can then integrate it into the view. This allows you to decouple the debugging process and hopefully make things more transparent as to what is functional and what is not.